# Add cells value until specific number is reached in Excel

Tags: excel, sum

Example:
Cell A1 has a value of 7

Cell B1 has a value of 4

Cell C1 has a value of 3

Cell D1 has a value of 5

Cell E1 has a value of 6

Excel function should add values until my specific value (15) or nearest to or less then to 15 is reached and return answer in a cell. For example excel should return value of 14 after adding Cell A1, B1 and C1. Excell should stop adding values at this point and should start adding the other cells until the 15 threshold and return value in new cell.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Should be fairly straightforward if you use a helper column - what have you tried so far?

Comment: I agree on an easy helper. But just for good fun one could try `=@LET(X,SCAN(0,A1:E1,LAMBDA(a,b,@a+@b)),SORTBY(X,ABS(X-15)))`