# Increment numbers when value changes in another column

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I currently have a column of letters in `B2:B11` alongside numbers that increment by `1` when letters appear consecutively (`C2:C11`). When a new letter appears, the sequence resets and starts from `1` again.

This is the formula I'm using:

```
=SCAN(0,B2:B11,
LAMBDA(a,b,
IF(OFFSET(b,-1,0)=b,
a+1,1)
)
)
```

It works fine when the letters are together in blocks, but when they are separated, any previous instances of a letter are forgotten about.

I want to find a solution that uses a single formula. I believe I'm on the right path using the new `SCAN()` function. Please **don't** suggest methods involving classic formulas or tables (I've already seen these).

The values returned should match those in `D2:D11`.

[image]

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806040/add-cells-value-until-specific-number-is-reached-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the array version in `E2`:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2,0,0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A11)),1),A2:A11)
```

or using `LET` for easier maintenance:

```
=LET(start, A2, range, A2:A11, 
  COUNTIF(OFFSET(start,0,0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),1),range))
```

This is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

The idea was taken from here: [Running Count Array Formula in Excel 365](https://excelmee.com/excel-formulas/running-count-array-formula-in-excel/)

**Note**: The third argument of `OFFSET` is optional, default is `1`, so it can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B2,"="&B2)
```

[image: spreadsheet]